# How to Find $E(X^2+Y^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question consisting of 5 parts. It is an old practice midterm question I wanted to explain it to my friend. But I seem to have forgotten how to do it.  I could do the easy parts A and B not the rest. I think D is $0$ since they are independent variables but I want to double check with you guys. BUT I need help with the rest.

QUESTION:
Given: $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. $X$ has mean $4$ and variance $14$. $X+Y$ has mean $6$ and variance $20$.

Solve:

A-)mean $Y \Rightarrow E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=6 \Rightarrow 4+E(Y)=6 \Rightarrow$ ANSWER: $E(Y)=2$

B-)variance $y \Rightarrow Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)=20 \Rightarrow 14+Var(Y)=20 \Rightarrow$ ANSWER: $Var(Y)=6$

C-) $E(X^2+Y^2)$: I can't figure this out.

D-)Correlation$(X,Y)$: Should be $0$ since they are independent right?

E-)$COV(XY,X+Y)$: $\Rightarrow COV(XY,X)+COV(XY,Y)$: Can't remember what is next.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For c) note that the variance is $V[X]=E[X^2]-E^2[X]$ so rearranging terms you can obtain the one you need

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
For c)

> $E[X^2+Y^2] = E[X^2]+E[Y^2] = \bigg( Var[X] + E^2[X] \bigg) + \bigg( Var[Y] + E^2[Y] \bigg)$

We used linearity of expectation and definition of variance here

For d) yes independence gives us that the correlation coefficient is zero. Note that the converse is not true in general. Cf. [Correlation and Dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

For e)

> $\Cov[XY, X+Y] = \Cov[XY,X] + \Cov[XY,Y] =E\bigg[(XY-E[XY])(X-E[X]) \bigg]+E\bigg[(XY-E[XY])(Y-E[Y]) \bigg] $